# how can i delete column with sum = 0 in excelhtml5 export

Tags: javascript, django, datatable, export-to-excel, xlsx

i use this code to export my table to excel in datatable-django.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('#example').DataTable( {

    dom: 'Bfrtip',

    buttons:

    [{extend: 'excelHtml5', text: 'export'}]

} );
```

} );

I have a table with 72 columns. I only want to export the columns to Excel whose cells sum is not zero. How can I do this?

i want just show the columns with sum>0

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the export options by extending the excelHtml5 button and customizing the resulting Excel file. please find example below that shows how you can achieve this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            text: 'Export',
            customize: function(xlsx) {
                var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml']; // Modify 'sheet1.xml' according to your sheet name
                
                // Retrieve the table data
                var tableData = $('#example').DataTable().data().toArray();
                
                // Calculate the sum of each column
                var columnSums = tableData.reduce(function(acc, row) {
                    row.forEach(function(cell, columnIndex) {
                        if (!acc[columnIndex]) {
                            acc[columnIndex] = 0;
                        }
                        acc[columnIndex] += parseFloat(cell) || 0;
                    });
                    return acc;
                }, []);
                
                // Identify columns with a sum of 0
                var columnsToDelete = columnSums.reduce(function(acc, sum, columnIndex) {
                    if (sum === 0) {
                        acc.push(columnIndex + 1); // Adjust the index since Excel uses 1-based indexing
                    }
                    return acc;
                }, []);
                
                // Loop through each row to delete columns with a sum of 0
                $('row', sheet).each(function() {
                    var cells = $('c', this);
                    
                    for (var i = columnsToDelete.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        var columnIndex = columnsToDelete[i];
                        $('c[r^="' + columnIndex + '"]', this).remove();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    ]
});
});
```

Please note that this solution assumes you have the necessary JavaScript and CSS files for the DataTable library and that you have initialized your DataTable with the appropriate options.

Comment: I have used this code and I am able to generate output, but filtering is not being applied and all columns are export to excel.

Comment: Please find the code for search filter!

`var filteredColumns = table.columns({ search: 'applied' }).indexes().toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

### Use `customizedData`

You can use `customizedData` callback function

```js
customizeData: function(data) {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        var columns = table.columns().data();
        var footer = table.columns().footer();

        var filteredColumns = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
          var columnData = columns[i].toArray();
          var columnSum = columnData.reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
          }, 0);

          if (columnSum > 0) {
            filteredColumns.push(columnData);
          }
        }

        data.body = filteredColumns;
        data.footer = footer;
        return data;
      }
```

### Explanation

We retrieve the column data using `table.columns().data()` and then calculate the sum of each column, filtering out the columns whose sum is not greater than zero.
After that we assign these filtered columns to `data.body` to replace the original data for export.

Comment: I added this part to my code, but when I click on the Excel export, it cannot generate the output. What could be the reason for this?